# Combining MySQL tables, also show when other table is nothing found

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder if a pure mysql query would be able to do the following:

This is my **tag table**:

```
+---------+-----+
| post_id | tag |
+---------+-----+
| 3       | lol |
| 3       | fun |
| 3       | hot |
+---------+-----+
```

and these tags belong to this table with **posts**:

```
+----+---------+---
| id | message | ...
+----+---------+---
| 1  | hello.. | ...
| 3  | nice..  | ...
+----+---------+---
```

Now what I want is **that the tag table is combined with the post table**, and that the tags are per post in a **seperate column called tags**, wherein all tags are located with a comma that seperates them:

```
+----+---------+--------------+---
| id | message | tags         | ...
+----+---------+--------------+---
| 1  | hello.. |              | ...
| 3  | nice..  | lol,fun,hot  | ...
+----+---------+--------------+---
```

I use this query at this moment and it works partly:

```
SELECT ri_posts.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ri_terms.hashtag SEPARATOR ', ') AS hashtags FROM ri_posts JOIN ri_terms ON ri_terms.parent_id = ri_posts.id
```

The problem with this query is that it only shows the posts that have tags in the tag table corresponding to the same parent id. **If a post does not have tags it is not included in the result.**

So now the result is (notice that the post with id 1 is gone):

```
+----+---------+--------------+---
| id | message | tags         | ...
+----+---------+--------------+---
| 3  | nice..  | lol,fun,hot  | ...
+----+---------+--------------+---
```

*How can I also show the posts without tags?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a left join -

```
SELECT ri_posts.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ri_terms.hashtag SEPARATOR ', ') AS hashtags 
FROM ri_posts 
LEFT JOIN ri_terms ON ri_terms.parent_id = ri_posts.id
GROUP BY re_posts.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `GROUP BY` to get multiple rows and a `LEFT JOIN` to get all posts, even those without tags:

```
SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t.hashtag SEPARATOR ', ') AS hashtags
FROM ri_posts p LEFT JOIN
     ri_terms t
    ON t.parent_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id;
```